# Fill pattern for Bar graph or StackedBar in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

How to use fill parttern for the Bar or Stacked Bar graph in Jasper Report?
Can anyone give some instructions or a easy example?
Many thanks.

My expecting is somethink like the graph beblow,and I want to use diagonal stroke to fill the bar.
[image]

Comment: You might look at a suitable [`Paint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Paint.html) implementation, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6935748/230513).

Comment: Hi Eric with the 2 duplicates (trashgod's shows the JFreeChart code) and mine shows how to implement it in jasper reports (JRChartCustomizer), you should be ok. However if you still have doubt's let me know